# How to serve page with Backbone Controller

Tags: backbone.js

Backbone define routes in its Controller in the following fashion. Does this mean every page of the site must have a copy of it? Or that every script must be load when the user reach the first page to make it work?

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Controller.extend({

  routes: {
    "help":                 "help",    // #help
    "search/:query":        "search",  // #search/kiwis
    "search/:query/p:page": "search"   // #search/kiwis/p7
  },
  help: function() {
    ...
  },
  search: function(query, page) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a hashbang router, those's aren't real pages. The urls look like:

- mysite/!#help
- mysite/!#search/kiwis
- etc.

It's used to route single page web apps. So you only serve one page and then render other pages by getting your data from a JSON web service.

Backbone.js allows you to route to sub pages on the client inside a page. This means you can change your URL to a book markable state and when you reload the page, backbone will reload that "section" of the page.

This routing should only be used inside a page and should not span across multiple pages.

You should be using your serverside MVC framework for that.

- CodeIgniter for PHP
- Express for node.js
- Rails for Ruby/Groovy
- MVC for ASP.NET
- Django for Python
- etc.

Comment: So how do we handle multiple pages?

Comment: @yvesamsellem you don't use a client side controller across multiple pages. You handle multiple pages using a server side controller.

Comment: Please, can you tell me more on this? Maybe some further reading links?

Comment: @yvesamsellem depends completely on what your server-side setup is. I listed some common server-side MVC frameworks.

Comment: I miss something. JavaScript helps us to move everything client-side. Why don't also manage multiple pages client-side? Every other JavaScript solution do not need a server. Why the client needs a server, is this from habits?

Comment: @yvesamsellem That's why if you do clientside routing you have only one page. And you do all your logic inside that one page pulling data from a JSON web service. You don't use links to different pages, you just have buttons that change and morph the current page. Besides you need a server to route web pages. I think your getting confused with what you do on the serve and what you do on the client

Comment: @Raynos What prevent us for using `window.location` and managing navigation client-side? You gave me assertions, but I need arguments to understand. Thanks.

Comment: @Raynos The role of the server is to serve JSON representation. The role of the client is to access to those representation in JavaScript. I don't see why a part of the client — the navigation management — have to be move to the server. I guess you are saying a File Server is not enough for a website, so please explain **why?**

Comment: @yvesamsellem you need the server for a database. You need the server for handling security. [Why you need a server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212859/why-dont-i-just-build-the-whole-web-app-in-javascript-and-javascript-html-templa/5212894#5212894). As for the routing yes you can do it client side but you can't navigate to different physical html pages on a fileserver. You use one html page on the file server and a JSON service. Then there's the whole supporting non-JS users.

Comment: @Raynos Say I'm writing a Twitter client. The server already exists and I'm not in charge of it. Where do I manage the navigation through the pages of my JavaScript client? Does a File Server is enough for that and how to do it? Thanks again.

Comment: @yvesamsellem I would set up a small node.js server to serve your web app that loads your twitter client data. In theory you can just server one big html file from a fileserver and it should work. Also best to [join the js chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript/) to discuss in greater detail